# Celery Django - customize task discovery

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

Instead of putting my celery tasks in tasks.py I'd like to put them in a couple different files.

Is there a way to tell Celery to look in these files for tasks?  Or is tasks.py hard-coded somewhere?

Here are my versions if it helps:

```
Django==1.8.7
celery==3.1.19
kombu==3.0.26
django-celery==3.1.17
```

Comment: Theoretically you could just import them into `tasks.py`, but the more I think about that idea the more I hate it.

Comment: which django, celery, and django-celery versions do you use?

Comment: @zsepi, I updated the question with those.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [celery docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest), since celery version 3.1 one doesn't need the `django-celery` app anymore, as django support is integrated into celery itself already.

As per the [tutorial](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html), one just needs an imported `app` object (instance of `celery.Celery`) imported in the project's `__init__.py`

[`app.autodiscover_tasks`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.html?highlight=autodiscover#celery.Celery.autodiscover_tasks) accepts two arguments,

- `packages`, which can easily be `lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS`
- `related_name`, which defaults to `tasks`, but it can be overwritten

Comment: That looks promising.  If I want tasks in multiple files would I just call app.autodiscover_tasks multiple times with different related_name arguments?

Comment: Looking at the source code, it looks like you can call it multiple times, as it updates the repo https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/3.1/celery/loaders/base.py#L249 (`Celery.autodiscover_tasks` delegates to `loader.autodiscover_tasks`)